# How to set environment variables (Map<String, String>) for docker container while creating pod in kubernetes cluster using java?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, java-client, kubernetes-cluster

I am trying to create Pod in kubernetes cluster to start the docker image. I used [⁠client-java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.kubernetes/client-java/8.0.0) version 8.0.0 to create pod cluster. I used this doc ⁠[kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/FluentExample.java#L39-L55) to create Pod cluster. But I couldn't set the environment variables for docker container.

**Code:**

```
Map<String, String> attributes = myObject.getAttributes(); //need to set this attributes as environment variables in pod creation
// create pod of a Kubernetes cluster
V1Pod pod = new V1PodBuilder().withNewMetadata().withName(serviceName).endMetadata()
                     .withNewSpec().addNewContainer().withName("www").withImage(dockerImage).endContainer().endSpec()
                        .build();
```

How to set environment variables `(Map<String, String>)` for docker container while creating pod?

Any inputs here really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [2n'd example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/FluentExample.java#L64) from Your referenced code and add `setEnv` [call](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/c5d7d3a7cadbd240008b6e76ba9d9c134e0c4b79/kubernetes/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/openapi/models/V1Container.java#L221) to `V1Container`.